# Java's String.split() drops trailing empty entries

Tags: java, split

I'm trying to parse some pipe delimited records. I've got this code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String[] components = "EN|1056209|||KA3NDL|L|||||||||||||||||||||".split("\\|");
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(components));
    }
}
```

You'd expect it to print:

```
[EN, 1056209, , , KA3NDL, L, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ]
```

But it doesn't. It prints:

```
[EN, 1056209, , , KA3NDL, L]
```

Accessing the `length` attribute of the `components` array shows it's being printed correctly.

Anybody know why this is/a workaround?

**EDIT:**

This works:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String[] components = "EN|1056209|||KA3NDL|L|||||||||||||||||||||".split("\\|", -1);
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(components));
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to print what you expect it to print - there's absolutely nothing between the pipes.

Comment: AnthonyGrist, thanks, I went and read the docs closer and figured it out.

Comment: Nick, instead of editing the question and its title in a non-standard manner, why didn't you just write an answer of your own? You can even accept it (after a delay).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) without the limit argument drops all trailing empty `Strings` from the result array. You'll need to include a limit:

```
String str = "EN|1056209|||KA3NDL|L|||||||||||||||||||||";
String[] components = str.split("\\|", -1);
```

From [`String.split(String, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

> If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length. If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

Calling `String.split(String)` is equivalent to calling the 2-argument `split` with a limit of *0*.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass a limit to the [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method so that the trailing empty strings are retained:

```
"EN|1056209|||KA3NDL|L|||||||||||||||||||||".split("\\|", -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the two-argument version of `split()` instead. It allows you to configure whether or not empty string should be returned as well.

Answer (score 1):

Have at look at [Splitter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) in the excellent Guava Libraries:

```
String input = "EN|1056209|||KA3NDL|L|||||||||||||||||||||";
Iterable<String> splitIter = Splitter.on("|").split(input);
System.out.println(splitIter);
```

output:

```
[EN, 1056209, , , KA3NDL, L, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ]
```